# Discover that a filled-in grid has a circle; fill in the area

Tags: loops, colors, grid, geometry, detect

[image]

Hi, I'm currently in the middle of a project where a new grid is added on to a chain of blocks on the grid every timestep.  How would I be able to detect that a circle has been made in the grid?  Given that all I have are the coordinates (x,y) and the color of each cell.  By "circle" I mean an area that is sealed off, as shown in the picture.

Thanks in advance!  By the way, I'm not asking how to click on a cell and apply the flood-fill algorithm.

The aftermath of the algorithm should produce this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to split all of your white (unfilled) squares into sets of squares adjacent to each other. Start with any white square, add all of its unfilled adjacent squares to the set, and keep doing it until you've included all of the squares.

Once you have those sets, you will have a "circle" (as you named it) if there are non-empty sets that do not contain any border squares. Then to fill these sets you just change the color of each member to blue.

If you have the sets from the previous step, when you add another brick you just need to consider the set that included the affected square to see if it has been split into two sets and whether either of these new sets may be a "circle".

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I'm left wondering, how do you know which set of white cells is the set you change to blue?  Here's what I think your directions are saying to do:

1)  Create a set. 

2) Add a white cell to the set, as well as its adjacent white cells, and so on.

But now, once I have multiple sets of white squares, how do I know which is the one that is enclosed?

Comment: Have an X by Y array of numbers indicating the number of the set that each square belongs to. You might not even need to have actual Set structures this way. Then, if you change the (x,y) square, just look up the set number in the array.

Comment: Okay I think I understand now.  If you have multiple sets of white squares, the set that you fill in is the set that doesn't have any border squares in it.

Comment: Say, in your first picture all of the white squares outside the "circle" would have number 1, and all white squares inside the circle would have number 2 assigned to them. Since none of the border squares have number 2, set 2 is a circle. If you add another blue square to a spot that belongs to set 1, you will need to see if set 1 has been split into two sets, and see if either set 1 or any of the two new sets are "circles". If there was no split, set 1 can only become a "circle" if the new blue square is a border square.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I ended up getting it to work.  I have it so that it finds cells in the outside set, and then it fills in all of the white cells that aren't in the outside set.  However, it's very taxing when the grid goes beyond 50x50 every time I create a new outside set, so my next problem will be finding a way to efficiently create the outside set.

Comment: Good luck, sounds like you are making progress.